# Cannot purge scheduled messages on celery for specific worker or queue

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I'm using celery with rabbitmq as the backend.
I have 5 workers.
When I do:

```
celery inspect scheduled
```

I get back all workers as empty e.g. worker1:

```
worker1: OK
    - empty -
```

apart from worker5 which lists 6 messages similar to the following:

```
{'eta': '2024-03-11T04:00:00+00:00', 'priority': 6, 'request': {'id': '528e53cc-acfe-4b35-a6ae-34a57c02526e', 'name': 'app.tasks.new_task', 'args': [], 'kwargs': {}, 'type': 'app.tasks.new_scheduled_task', 'hostname': 'worker5', 'time_start': None, 'acknowledged': False, 'delivery_info': {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery', 'priority': 0, 'redelivered': True}, 'worker_pid': None}}
```

Trying to purge the messages e.g.:

```
celery multi restart worker5 --purge
```

or

```
celery -A celery_worker.celery purge
```

has no effect.

Also, I have tried using rabbitmqctl:

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues
```

gives me a list of queues of which one called "celery" has 6 items in it (matching the number of messages in worker5)

However, trying to purge it using:

```
 rabbitmqctl purge_queue celery
```

has no effect

With the above, I expected the queue called "celery" to have zero items in it and worker5 to have zero messages in it.

Any other suggestions using `celery` or `rabbitmqctl` commands?

Thanks